# Show Ordinals as superscripts

Tags: vb.net, converters, superscript, ordinals

I have the below code for adding ordinals such as st,rd,th and so on..

```
Private ordinals As String() = New String() {"", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", _
"th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", _
"th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", _
"th", "th", "th", "st", "nd", "rd", _
"th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", _
"th", "st"}
```

For getting date I'm writing it as follows:

```
Dim D As DateTime = Me.PresentDate.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
Dim todate As String = D.Day.ToString() + ordinals(D.Day)
```

Result:

5th

But I would like to get the result as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the superscript characters in the first place?

```
Dim ordinals = {"", "ˢᵗ", "ⁿᵈ", "ʳᵈ", "ᵗʰ", "ᵗʰ", _
                "ᵗʰ", "ᵗʰ", "ᵗʰ", "ᵗʰ", "ᵗʰ", "ᵗʰ", _
                "ᵗʰ", "ᵗʰ", "ᵗʰ", "ᵗʰ", "ᵗʰ", "ᵗʰ", _
                "ᵗʰ", "ᵗʰ", "ᵗʰ", "ˢᵗ", "ⁿᵈ", "ⁿᵈ", _
                "ᵗʰ", "ᵗʰ", "ᵗʰ", "ᵗʰ", "ᵗʰ", "ᵗʰ", _
                "ᵗʰ", "ˢᵗ"}

Dim D = DateTime.Now
Dim todate = D.Day.ToString() + ordinals(D.Day) ' todate = 6ᵗʰ
```

or create a simple lookup dictionary:

```
Dim ordinals = {"", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", _
                "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", _
                "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", _
                "th", "th", "th", "st", "nd", "rd", _
                "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", _
                "th", "st"}

Dim supers = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".Zip("ᵃᵇᶜᵈᵉᶠᵍʰⁱʲᵏˡᵐⁿᵒᵖXʳˢᵗᵘᵛʷˣʸᶻ", AddressOf Tuple.Create) _
                                         .ToDictionary(Function(t) t.Item1, Function(t) t.Item2)
Dim D = Date.Now
Dim todate = D.Day.ToString() + String.Join("", ordinals(D.Day).Select(Function(c) supers(c)))
```

Comment: @Dominic-Thanks for the simple logic :)

Answer (score 1):

If you were trying to display this in a rich text box then you could do the following.  This assumes you have a rich text box on a form and have delared your string of ordinals.  In the load event of the form add the following:

```
 Dim D As DateTime = CDate(Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))
   Dim todate As String = D.Day.ToString() + ordinals(D.Day)
        With RichTextBox1
            .SelectionFont = New Font("Lucinda Console", 12)
            .SelectedText = D.Day.ToString()
            .SelectionCharOffset = 5
            .SelectedText = ordinals(D.Day)
        End With
```

From here you should be able to play with the formatting.  However as a caveat this only seems to work with a rich textbox or control derived from one